# How to mock a "<script>" in react jest unit test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

My js file which need to test import a iconfont.js lib to use icon in this component. But when i run npm test, it show:

```
Test suite failed to run

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined
```

when i see iconfont.js, it have below code about this error:

```
h=(a=document.getElementsByTagName("script"))[a.length-1].getAttribute("data-injectcss");
```

I try to use `document.body.innerHTML` in test file to mock a , but no use.

I'm newbee for react unit test, pls help me.

Comment: You preferably shouldn't. JSDOM may behave like real DOM but not necessarily. Mock `document.getElementsByTagName` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this issue by myself.
I use `require()` instead of `import` and assign `<script></script>` to `document.body.innerHTML` before require.
like below:

```
//old
import component from 'need-test-component';
//new
document.body.innerHTML = '<script></script>'
const component = require('need-test-component').default;
```